# Optimizing GROUP BY of jsonb array values in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization, jsonb, database-indexes, postgresql-12

**Updated for better hardware**

I have the following simplified schema in Postgres12 whereby a *dataset* has many *cfiles* and each cfile has *property_values* stored as jsonb:

```sql
SELECT * FROM cfiles;
 id | dataset_id |                property_values (jsonb)                
----+------------+-----------------------------------------------
  1 |          1 | {"Sample Names": ["SampA", "SampB"], (...other properties)}
  2 |          1 | {"Sample Names": ["SampA", "SampC"], (...other properties)}
  3 |          1 | {"Sample Names": ["SampD"],          (...other properties)}
```

Some "Sample Names" arrays are large and may have up to 100 short strings (~1K chars total)

I am using the query below to group by each of the values in the "Sample Names" jsonb arrays. The query gives the results I want but it takes around **15 seconds** on **~45K rows** (explain query plan at the bottom) running on aws t2.micro with **1vCPU and 1GB ram**

```sql
SELECT
jsonb_array_elements_text(property_values -> 'Sample Names') as sample_names,
max(cfiles.last_modified) as last_modified,
string_agg(DISTINCT(users.email), ', ') as user_email,
string_agg(DISTINCT(groups.name), ', ') as group_name
FROM cfiles
JOIN datasets ON cfiles.dataset_id=datasets.id
LEFT JOIN user_permissions ON (user_permissions.cfile_id=cfiles.id OR user_permissions.dataset_id=datasets.id)
LEFT JOIN users on users.id=user_permissions.user_id
LEFT JOIN group_permissions ON (group_permissions.cfile_id=cfiles.id OR group_permissions.dataset_id=datasets.id)
LEFT JOIN groups ON groups.id=group_permissions.group_id
LEFT JOIN user_groups ON groups.id=user_groups.group_id
WHERE
cfiles.tid=5
-- Query needs to support sample name filtering eg:
-- AND property_values ->> 'Sample Names' like '%test%'
-- As well as filtering by columns from the other joined tables
GROUP BY sample_names
-- Below is required for pagination
ORDER BY "sample_names" desc NULLS LAST
```

All of the ID columns and join columns are indexed.

I have tried to reduce the query further but found it tricky because it's difficult to correlate incremental reductions with improvements and my final result needs to include everything.

Just the cfiles without any joins still takes ~12 seconds:

```sql
SELECT
jsonb_array_elements_text(property_values -> 'Sample Names') as sample_names,
max(cfiles.last_modified) as last_modified
FROM cfiles
WHERE
cfiles.tid=5
GROUP BY sample_names
ORDER BY "sample_names" desc NULLS LAST
LIMIT 20
OFFSET 0
```

I tried using more of a CTE pattern below, but it was slower and didn't produce the correct results

```sql
WITH cf AS (
  SELECT
  cfiles.id as id,
  cfiles.dataset_id as dataset_id,
  jsonb_array_elements_text(property_values -> 'Sample Names') as sample_names,
  cfiles.last_modified as last_modified
  FROM cfiles
  WHERE
  cfiles.tid=5
  GROUP BY sample_names, id, dataset_id, last_modified
  ORDER BY "sample_names" desc NULLS LAST
  LIMIT 20
  OFFSET 0
)

SELECT cf.sample_names as sample_names,
max(cf.last_modified) as last_modified,
string_agg(DISTINCT(users.email), ', ') as user_email,
string_agg(DISTINCT(groups.name), ', ') as group_name
FROM cf
JOIN datasets ON cf.dataset_id=datasets.id
LEFT JOIN user_permissions ON (user_permissions.cfile_id=cf.id OR user_permissions.dataset_id=datasets.id)
LEFT JOIN users on users.id=user_permissions.user_id
LEFT JOIN group_permissions ON (group_permissions.cfile_id=cf.id OR group_permissions.dataset_id=datasets.id)
LEFT JOIN groups ON groups.id=group_permissions.group_id
LEFT JOIN user_groups ON groups.id=user_groups.group_id
GROUP BY sample_names
ORDER BY "sample_names" desc NULLS LAST
```

Is there any other way I can improve the performance of this query ideally down to a just few seconds? I can rearrange it, use temp tables and indexes, whichever works best.

Is it likely that increasing the RAM will help?

**Updated explain analyze verbose:**

```sql
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  QUERY PLAN                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Limit  (cost=1046905.99..1046907.17 rows=20 width=104) (actual time=15394.929..15409.256 rows=20 loops=1)
   Output: (jsonb_array_elements_text((cfiles.property_values -> 'Sample Names'::text))), (max(cfiles.last_modified)), (string_agg(DISTINCT (users.email)::text, ', '::text)), (string_agg(DISTINCT (groups.name)::text, ', '::text))
   ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=1046905.99..1130738.74 rows=1426200 width=104) (actual time=15394.927..15409.228 rows=20 loops=1)
         Output: (jsonb_array_elements_text((cfiles.property_values -> 'Sample Names'::text))), max(cfiles.last_modified), string_agg(DISTINCT (users.email)::text, ', '::text), string_agg(DISTINCT (groups.name)::text, ', '::text)
         Group Key: (jsonb_array_elements_text((cfiles.property_values -> 'Sample Names'::text)))
         ->  Sort  (cost=1046905.99..1057967.74 rows=4424700 width=104) (actual time=15394.877..15400.483 rows=11067 loops=1)
               Output: (jsonb_array_elements_text((cfiles.property_values -> 'Sample Names'::text))), cfiles.last_modified, users.email, groups.name
               Sort Key: (jsonb_array_elements_text((cfiles.property_values -> 'Sample Names'::text))) DESC NULLS LAST
               Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 163288kB
               ->  ProjectSet  (cost=41.40..74530.20 rows=4424700 width=104) (actual time=0.682..2933.628 rows=3399832 loops=1)
                     Output: jsonb_array_elements_text((cfiles.property_values -> 'Sample Names'::text)), cfiles.last_modified, users.email, groups.name
                     ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=41.40..51964.23 rows=44247 width=526) (actual time=0.587..1442.326 rows=46031 loops=1)
                           Output: cfiles.property_values, cfiles.last_modified, users.email, groups.name
                           Join Filter: ((user_permissions.cfile_id = cfiles.id) OR (user_permissions.dataset_id = datasets.id))
                           Rows Removed by Join Filter: 2391425
                           ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=38.55..11694.81 rows=44247 width=510) (actual time=0.473..357.751 rows=46016 loops=1)
                                 Output: cfiles.property_values, cfiles.last_modified, cfiles.id, datasets.id, groups.name
                                 Join Filter: ((group_permissions.cfile_id = cfiles.id) OR (group_permissions.dataset_id = datasets.id))
                                 Rows Removed by Join Filter: 616311
                                 ->  Hash Join  (cost=35.81..4721.54 rows=44247 width=478) (actual time=0.388..50.189 rows=44255 loops=1)
                                       Output: cfiles.property_values, cfiles.last_modified, cfiles.id, datasets.id
                                       Inner Unique: true
                                       Hash Cond: (cfiles.dataset_id = datasets.id)
                                       ->  Seq Scan on public.cfiles  (cost=0.00..4568.77 rows=44247 width=478) (actual time=0.012..20.676 rows=44255 loops=1)
                                             Output: cfiles.id, cfiles.tid, cfiles.uuid, cfiles.dataset_id, cfiles.path, cfiles.name, cfiles.checksum, cfiles.size, cfiles.last_modified, cfiles.content_type, cfiles.locked, cfiles.property_values, cfiles.created_at, cfiles.updated_at
                                             Filter: (cfiles.tid = 5)
                                             Rows Removed by Filter: 1567
                                       ->  Hash  (cost=28.14..28.14 rows=614 width=8) (actual time=0.363..0.363 rows=614 loops=1)
                                             Output: datasets.id
                                             Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 32kB
                                             ->  Seq Scan on public.datasets  (cost=0.00..28.14 rows=614 width=8) (actual time=0.004..0.194 rows=614 loops=1)
                                                   Output: datasets.id
                                 ->  Materialize  (cost=2.74..4.39 rows=9 width=48) (actual time=0.000..0.003 rows=14 loops=44255)
                                       Output: group_permissions.cfile_id, group_permissions.dataset_id, groups.name
                                       ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=2.74..4.35 rows=9 width=48) (actual time=0.049..0.071 rows=14 loops=1)
                                             Output: group_permissions.cfile_id, group_permissions.dataset_id, groups.name
                                             Hash Cond: (user_groups.group_id = groups.id)
                                             ->  Seq Scan on public.user_groups  (cost=0.00..1.38 rows=38 width=8) (actual time=0.003..0.011 rows=38 loops=1)
                                                   Output: user_groups.id, user_groups.tid, user_groups.user_id, user_groups.group_id, user_groups.created_at, user_groups.updated_at
                                             ->  Hash  (cost=2.62..2.62 rows=9 width=56) (actual time=0.039..0.039 rows=9 loops=1)
                                                   Output: group_permissions.cfile_id, group_permissions.dataset_id, groups.name, groups.id
                                                   Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9kB
                                                   ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=1.20..2.62 rows=9 width=56) (actual time=0.021..0.035 rows=9 loops=1)
                                                         Output: group_permissions.cfile_id, group_permissions.dataset_id, groups.name, groups.id
                                                         Hash Cond: (groups.id = group_permissions.group_id)
                                                         ->  Seq Scan on public.groups  (cost=0.00..1.24 rows=24 width=40) (actual time=0.003..0.008 rows=24 loops=1)
                                                               Output: groups.id, groups.tid, groups.name, groups.description, groups.default_uview, groups.created_at, groups.updated_at
                                                         ->  Hash  (cost=1.09..1.09 rows=9 width=24) (actual time=0.010..0.010 rows=9 loops=1)
                                                               Output: group_permissions.cfile_id, group_permissions.dataset_id, group_permissions.group_id
                                                               Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9kB
                                                               ->  Seq Scan on public.group_permissions  (cost=0.00..1.09 rows=9 width=24) (actual time=0.003..0.006 rows=9 loops=1)
                                                                     Output: group_permissions.cfile_id, group_permissions.dataset_id, group_permissions.group_id
                           ->  Materialize  (cost=2.85..4.78 rows=52 width=48) (actual time=0.000..0.010 rows=52 loops=46016)
                                 Output: user_permissions.cfile_id, user_permissions.dataset_id, users.email
                                 ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=2.85..4.52 rows=52 width=48) (actual time=0.037..0.076 rows=52 loops=1)
                                       Output: user_permissions.cfile_id, user_permissions.dataset_id, users.email
                                       Inner Unique: true
                                       Hash Cond: (user_permissions.user_id = users.id)
                                       ->  Seq Scan on public.user_permissions  (cost=0.00..1.52 rows=52 width=24) (actual time=0.003..0.014 rows=52 loops=1)
                                             Output: user_permissions.id, user_permissions.tid, user_permissions.user_id, user_permissions.dataset_id, user_permissions.cfile_id, user_permissions.read, user_permissions.share, user_permissions.write_meta, user_permissions.manage_files, user_permissions.delete_files, user_permissions.task_id, user_permissions.notified_at, user_permissions.first_downloaded_at, user_permissions.created_at, user_permissions.updated_at
                                       ->  Hash  (cost=2.38..2.38 rows=38 width=40) (actual time=0.029..0.030 rows=38 loops=1)
                                             Output: users.email, users.id
                                             Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 11kB
                                             ->  Seq Scan on public.users  (cost=0.00..2.38 rows=38 width=40) (actual time=0.004..0.016 rows=38 loops=1)
                                                   Output: users.email, users.id
 Planning Time: 0.918 ms
 Execution Time: 15442.689 ms
(67 rows)

Time: 15575.174 ms (00:15.575)
```

**Update 2**

After increasing work_mem to 256mb, the cfiles without any joins query dropped from 12sec to 2sec, but the full query is still at 11 seconds - new plan below

```
 Limit  (cost=1197580.62..1197582.26 rows=20 width=104) (actual time=11049.784..11057.060 rows=20 loops=1)
   Output: (jsonb_array_elements_text((cfiles.property_values -> 'Sample Names'::text))), (max(cfiles.last_modified)), (string_agg(DISTINCT (users.email)::text, ', '::text)), (string_agg(DISTINCT (groups.name)::text, ', '::text))
   ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=1197580.62..1313691.62 rows=1423800 width=104) (actual time=11049.783..11057.056 rows=20 loops=1)
         Output: (jsonb_array_elements_text((cfiles.property_values -> 'Sample Names'::text))), max(cfiles.last_modified), string_agg(DISTINCT (users.email)::text, ', '::text), string_agg(DISTINCT (groups.name)::text, ', '::text)
         Group Key: (jsonb_array_elements_text((cfiles.property_values -> 'Sample Names'::text)))
         ->  Sort  (cost=1197580.62..1215107.62 rows=7010800 width=80) (actual time=11049.741..11051.064 rows=11067 loops=1)
               Output: (jsonb_array_elements_text((cfiles.property_values -> 'Sample Names'::text))), cfiles.last_modified, users.email, groups.name
               Sort Key: (jsonb_array_elements_text((cfiles.property_values -> 'Sample Names'::text))) DESC NULLS LAST
               Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 163248kB
               ->  ProjectSet  (cost=39.41..88894.93 rows=7010800 width=80) (actual time=0.314..1309.381 rows=3399832 loops=1)
                     Output: jsonb_array_elements_text((cfiles.property_values -> 'Sample Names'::text)), cfiles.last_modified, users.email, groups.name
                     ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=39.41..53139.85 rows=70108 width=502) (actual time=0.230..413.324 rows=46031 loops=1)
                           Output: cfiles.property_values, cfiles.last_modified, users.email, groups.name
                           Hash Cond: (groups.id = user_groups.group_id)
                           ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=37.55..51994.13 rows=44279 width=510) (actual time=0.218..405.437 rows=44535 loops=1)
                                 Output: cfiles.property_values, cfiles.last_modified, users.email, groups.name, groups.id
                                 Join Filter: ((user_permissions.cfile_id = cfiles.id) OR (user_permissions.dataset_id = datasets.id))
                                 Rows Removed by Join Filter: 2313897
                                 ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=34.70..11695.59 rows=44279 width=500) (actual time=0.166..99.664 rows=44520 loops=1)
                                       Output: cfiles.property_values, cfiles.last_modified, cfiles.id, datasets.id, groups.name, groups.id
                                       Join Filter: ((group_permissions.cfile_id = cfiles.id) OR (group_permissions.dataset_id = datasets.id))
                                       Rows Removed by Join Filter: 396532
                                       ->  Hash Join  (cost=33.16..4718.97 rows=44279 width=478) (actual time=0.141..30.449 rows=44255 loops=1)
                                             Output: cfiles.property_values, cfiles.last_modified, cfiles.id, datasets.id
                                             Inner Unique: true
                                             Hash Cond: (cfiles.dataset_id = datasets.id)
                                             ->  Seq Scan on public.cfiles  (cost=0.00..4568.77 rows=44279 width=478) (actual time=0.016..12.724 rows=44255 loops=1)
                                                   Output: cfiles.id, cfiles.tid, cfiles.uuid, cfiles.dataset_id, cfiles.path, cfiles.name, cfiles.checksum, cfiles.size, cfiles.last_modified, cfiles.content_type, cfiles.locked, cfiles.property_values, cfiles.created_at, cfiles.updated_at
                                                   Filter: (cfiles.tid = 5)
                                                   Rows Removed by Filter: 1567
                                             ->  Hash  (cost=25.48..25.48 rows=614 width=8) (actual time=0.119..0.120 rows=614 loops=1)
                                                   Output: datasets.id
                                                   Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 32kB
                                                   ->  Index Only Scan using datasets_pkey on public.datasets  (cost=0.28..25.48 rows=614 width=8) (actual time=0.010..0.057 rows=614 loops=1)
                                                         Output: datasets.id
                                                         Heap Fetches: 0
                                       ->  Materialize  (cost=1.54..2.70 rows=9 width=38) (actual time=0.000..0.001 rows=9 loops=44255)
                                             Output: group_permissions.cfile_id, group_permissions.dataset_id, groups.name, groups.id
                                             ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=1.54..2.65 rows=9 width=38) (actual time=0.015..0.021 rows=9 loops=1)
                                                   Output: group_permissions.cfile_id, group_permissions.dataset_id, groups.name, groups.id
                                                   Inner Unique: true
                                                   Hash Cond: (group_permissions.group_id = groups.id)
                                                   ->  Seq Scan on public.group_permissions  (cost=0.00..1.09 rows=9 width=24) (actual time=0.002..0.003 rows=9 loops=1)
                                                         Output: group_permissions.id, group_permissions.tid, group_permissions.group_id, group_permissions.dataset_id, group_permissions.cfile_id, group_permissions.read, group_permissions.share, group_permissions.write_meta, group_permissions.manage_files, group_permissions.delete_files, group_permissions.task_id, group_permissions.notified_at, group_permissions.first_downloaded_at, group_permissions.created_at, group_permissions.updated_at
                                                   ->  Hash  (cost=1.24..1.24 rows=24 width=22) (actual time=0.009..0.010 rows=24 loops=1)
                                                         Output: groups.name, groups.id
                                                         Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 10kB
                                                         ->  Seq Scan on public.groups  (cost=0.00..1.24 rows=24 width=22) (actual time=0.003..0.006 rows=24 loops=1)
                                                               Output: groups.name, groups.id
                                 ->  Materialize  (cost=2.85..4.78 rows=52 width=42) (actual time=0.000..0.003 rows=52 loops=44520)
                                       Output: user_permissions.cfile_id, user_permissions.dataset_id, users.email
                                       ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=2.85..4.52 rows=52 width=42) (actual time=0.021..0.036 rows=52 loops=1)
                                             Output: user_permissions.cfile_id, user_permissions.dataset_id, users.email
                                             Inner Unique: true
                                             Hash Cond: (user_permissions.user_id = users.id)
                                             ->  Seq Scan on public.user_permissions  (cost=0.00..1.52 rows=52 width=24) (actual time=0.002..0.005 rows=52 loops=1)
                                                   Output: user_permissions.id, user_permissions.tid, user_permissions.user_id, user_permissions.dataset_id, user_permissions.cfile_id, user_permissions.read, user_permissions.share, user_permissions.write_meta, user_permissions.manage_files, user_permissions.delete_files, user_permissions.task_id, user_permissions.notified_at, user_permissions.first_downloaded_at, user_permissions.created_at, user_permissions.updated_at
                                             ->  Hash  (cost=2.38..2.38 rows=38 width=34) (actual time=0.016..0.017 rows=38 loops=1)
                                                   Output: users.email, users.id
                                                   Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 11kB
                                                   ->  Seq Scan on public.users  (cost=0.00..2.38 rows=38 width=34) (actual time=0.002..0.010 rows=38 loops=1)
                                                         Output: users.email, users.id
                           ->  Hash  (cost=1.38..1.38 rows=38 width=8) (actual time=0.009..0.010 rows=38 loops=1)
                                 Output: user_groups.group_id
                                 Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 10kB
                                 ->  Seq Scan on public.user_groups  (cost=0.00..1.38 rows=38 width=8) (actual time=0.002..0.005 rows=38 loops=1)
                                       Output: user_groups.group_id
 Planning Time: 0.990 ms
 Execution Time: 11081.013 ms
(69 rows)

Time: 11143.367 ms (00:11.143)
```

Comment: Hey there. The query isn't using the index you created, since the expression isn't in the `WHERE` clause. Can you share the create table statement with the indexes? Since there are many tables involved, it would make things easier if you could create a minimal reproducible example. Is `datasets.id` indexed?

Comment: Thanks @JimJones `datasets.id` is indexed and while I was preparing minimal example I realized without the LEFT JOINs it's only 3sec so I'm going to try refactor that part and report back

Comment: What do you get if you eliminate all the tables but cfiles?

Comment: Taking one minute to sort 3,399,832 rows occupying 163,296kB is egregious.  What is your hardware like?

Comment: Thanks @jjanes you were correct my laptop hardware was too slow - updated everything for aws and also the query plan came out a little different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you will have a tough time doing much better with the current schema.  Could you normalize the data do you have a table with one row per `(tid,"Sample Names",id)` combo, or perhaps just one row per unique ("Sample Names") or per `(tid,"Sample Names")`?

Although I don't think there is a generic answer to "As well as filtering by columns from the other joined tables".  An answer would depend on how selective the filter is and whether it is indexable.

Comment: Right gotcha, unfortunately I'm tied to the current schema but maybe I can implement some more normalized cache tables. I tried increasing the `work_mem` to 256MB (double the `Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 163288kB` from the explain) following [this](https://andreigridnev.com/blog/2016-04-16-increase-work_mem-parameter-in-postgresql-to-make-expensive-queries-faster/) post but it didn't seem to have any effect. Would this be because it's reached it's processing max? Or is aws imposing other limits?

Comment: Oh actually it did have a huge effect on just the cfiles query - from 12 seconds down to 2 seconds, so maybe I can re-work the joins - I've updated with the new plan

Comment: Increasing work_mem for a sort usually doesn't do much good until it is large enough to do the entire sort in memory.  That can often by around 3 fold the external merge disk usage as disk format is more compact than in memory format.